# Modelling question: example of a physical phenomenon with this jump condition at an interface?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, solid-mechanics, coupling

in our finite element class we were talking about interface problems our teacher came up with the following, where $K_i$ are two given functions and $u_i$ is the restriction of the solution $u$ to $\Omega_i$.

$$-\nabla \cdot (K_i \nabla u_i) =f_i \text{ in } \Omega_i$$
$$u_i=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega  \cap \Omega_i$$
$$n_1 \cdot K_1 \nabla u_1 + n_2 \cdot \nabla u_2 = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma:=\partial \bar{\Omega_1} \cap \partial \bar{\Omega_2}$$
$$[u]=0 \text{ on } \Gamma$$

We assumed that $\Omega_2 \subset \Omega_1$, i.e. one domain is included in another.

**Question: what is the physical meaning of the condition $$n_1 \cdot K_1 \nabla u_1 + n_2 \cdot K_2 \nabla u_2 = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma$$ ? Can you provide a simple example where this condition means something from the physical standpoint?**

For sure it is a continuity condition, but I cannot imagine a physical situation where this occurs. Examples from elasticity/solid mechanics are of course welcome.

Answer (score 6):

$\vec\Phi = K_i \nabla u_i$ is the *flux* across the interface. For example, if $u$ is the thermal energy density and $K$ the thermal conductivity, then $\vec\Phi$ is the thermal energy flux. Energy conservation then dictates that whatever flows into the interface on one side ($\vec n_1 \cdot K_1 \nabla \vec\Phi_1$) better be equal to what flows out on the other side ($-\vec n_2 \cdot K_2 \nabla \vec\Phi_2$). This then results in the condition you show.

Similarly, if $u$ is the concentration of a substance diffusing in a medium, where the diffusion constant is $K$, you end up with the same condition by considering the conservation of mass of the substance.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth, that was exactly what I was looking for. One side question. If I have instead a problem like this (where $\Omega_2 \subset \Omega_1$, so $\Gamma = \partial \Omega_2$): 

$$- \nabla \cdot ( K_i \nabla u_i) = f_i \text{ in } \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$$
$$u= 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega_1$$
$$[u]=0 \text{ on } \Gamma$$
$$n_1 \cdot K_1 \nabla u_1=0 \text{ on } \Gamma$$

I'd say that that Neumann boundary condition is *not* physical, meaning that energy is not conserved. Is this correct?

Comment: It just means that from that one side no energy flows. That's fine -- the interface might be insulated. But this only makes sense if no energy flows from the other side either.

Comment: Apparently the question implies that n1 and n2 are in general two different vectors. On the other hand, in this answer n1 and n2 would not be different (other than the sign) because it is the same interface.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I think that's a mistake in the question.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Of course, indeed what I meant is $n_1 = -n_2$.

Comment: Ok, but then why is it quantity u1 on one side of the interface but a different quantity u2 on the other side? I guess to make this meaningful for the energy flow interpretation, the interface has to separate two different species: on one side it is the temperature of one species and on the other side it is the temperature of the other one, and the energy flux, normal to the surface, is continuous.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Think of $K_1 \nabla u_1$ as "$K \nabla u$ evaluated on the $\Omega_1$ side of the interface $\Gamma$". $u$ is the temperature or energy density in the entire domain, it is just computed as two functions that live on the two parts of the domain respectively (that is: the *restriction* of $u$ onto the subdomains).

Comment: No, that would not be the standard way to write it in science literature. The statement of the problem is that K1 and K2 are two different functions, and u1 and u2 are two different quantities, otherwise the same symbol would be used for both. It makes sense that the condition expresses continuity of thermal energy flux through the interface, but the interface has to separate two species to justify using different symbols for the temperatures on the opposite sides of the interface. Why would K1 and K2 be different? If they apply to different species that makes sense, otherwise not so much.

Comment: @MaximUmansky The notation used by OP is exactly what (non-overlapping) domain decomposition people would use, where $u_k$ is exactly the restriction of $u$ to subdomain $\Omega_i$. As for different values of $K$: Imagine two materials coming together at $\Gamma$, with different thermal conductivities $K_1,K_2$. If $u$ is the temperature, and $u$ is continuous at $\Gamma$, and so is the normal flux $-K\nabla u\cdot n$ -- in other words, $\left([-K\nabla u]|_{\Omega_1}\right)|_\Gamma \cdot n = \left([-K\nabla u]|_{\Omega_2}\right)|_\Gamma \cdot n$ That's exactly what the stated condition is.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth Ok, if the interface separates two different materials (or different species) the notation would make sense for a description in a science paper or textbook; but that perhaps would be good to include in the answer, otherwise it looks ambiguous - B.C. set at some kind of interface in the middle of the domain but K1 and K2 are different.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Wolfgang Bangerth's explanation of temperature and concentration, let me give an other application where such interface conditions arise: (linear) elasticity, which has a similar structure to the elliptic equation in your example. Consider the situation with no interface first. Then the equilibrium, constitutive and kinematic equations of linear elasticity read
\begin{gather}
   \sigma\cdot\nabla = \mathbf{0}, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega \\
   \sigma = \mathcal{C}:\varepsilon, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega \\
   \varepsilon = \nabla^s\mathbf{u}, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega
\end{gather}
with properly defined boundary conditions, where $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$, $\mathcal{C}$ is the Hooke tensor, $\sigma$ is the Cauchy stress tensor, $\varepsilon$ is the linearized strain tensor and $\mathbf{u}$ is the displacement vector.

A physically equivalent formulation is when these equations are written for each subdomain and the subdomains are tied together:
\begin{gather}
   \sigma_i\cdot\nabla = \mathbf{0}, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega_i \\
   \sigma_i = \mathcal{C}_i:\varepsilon_i, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega_i \\
   \varepsilon_i = \nabla^s\mathbf{u}_i, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\Omega_i
\end{gather}
with the continuity of the displacement field (no interface separation) and the traction field (Newton's third axiom):
\begin{gather}
   \mathbf{u}_1| = \mathbf{u}_2, \quad \mathbf{x} \in \Gamma \\
   \mathbf{t}_i = -\mathbf{t}_j, \quad \mathbf{x} \in \Gamma.
\end{gather}
By Cauchy's theorem, the traction vector can be expressed with the stress tensor as
\begin{equation}
   \sigma_i|_\Gamma\cdot\mathbf{n}_i = -\sigma_j|_\Gamma\cdot\mathbf{n}_j.
\end{equation}
If you substitute the constitutive and kinematics equations into this equation, you get the structurally same condition as what your teacher wrote. Here, the fourth-order tensor $\mathcal{C}_i$ corresponds to the scalar $K_i$ and $\mathbf{u}_i$ corresponds to $u_i$.

*Remark 1*: The above formulae hold even if $\Omega_2 \not\subset \Omega_1$ (i.e. $\Gamma$ is not closed), but $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ have a common boundary (i.e. $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$).

*Remark 2*: The same considerations hold for multiple subdomains, in which two neighbouring subdomains $\Omega_i$ and $\Omega_j$ are separated by the interface $\Gamma_{ij}$.

*Remark 3*: Note that writing the PDEs for each subdomain independently and then tying them together resembles a domain decomposition method. Indeed, if the continuity conditions are imposed by a Lagrange multiplier (which turns out to be equivalent to the interface traction), the resulting mixed formulation is the continuous analogue of the FETI domain decomposition method.

Comment: Yes, nice example! The (normal) fluxes in this case correspond to tractions.